# Create Jquery dropdown dynamically inside bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a dropdown for each entry in the bootstrap table. These entries are received from the service methods.
Here is how I am trying to create the dropdown,

```
 var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("class", "drop col-sm-6");

  if(obj.interest=="Not Interested")
  {
     //alert("Inside not interested");
combo.append("<option>" + obj.interest + "</option>");
combo.append("<option>Interested</option>");
combo.append("<option>Call on Later</option>");
  }
   if(obj.interest=="Interested")
  {
      //alert("Inside Interested");
combo.append("<option>" + obj.interest + "</option>");
combo.append("<option>"+"Not Interested"+"</option>");
combo.append("<option>"+"Call on Later"+"</option>");
  }
   if(obj.interest=="Call on Later")
  {
      //alert("Inside Call on later");
combo.append("<option>" + obj.interest + "</option>");
combo.append("<option>"+"Interested"+"</option>");
combo.append("<option>"+"Not Interested"+"</option>");
  }
```

I am then adding this dropdown in the table as,

```
    t.row.add( [

      obj.clientName,
      obj.companyName,
      obj.contactNumber,
      obj.emailId,
       companytype.companyType,
      category.categoryName,
      combo,
      obj.updatedDate
       //and so on as based on number of your columns
   ]).draw();
```

But the dropdown is not getting displayed in the table. Instead it shows "Object" in the table.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to pack all your new elements into a string and then at the end only call append once

Comment: Thank you @DimitrisCSD, but it is still not working .